# Why is the app aspect different when JavaScript debugging is activated?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

While working on my ASP .NET Web App I encountered this difference between the "normal" debugging mode and the one with javascript debug enabled.

I used Chrome in the images below, but the differences are visible in other Edge and IE too.

DATE input in normal debug mode

[image]

DATE input with JS debug mode enabled
[image]

Normal mode
[image]

JS debug mode enabled
[image]

TIME input with JS debug mode enabled
[image]

These along with many other elements are changed.

Comment: Are you using any component library + which browser?

Comment: I am using Razor Pages.